# What does the following javascript line mean

Tags: javascript

I came across this line of code

```
var applicationtypes = {};
```

What is the purpose of the curly braces

Comment: Create an empty object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is call an object initialiser, also sometimes referred to as a object literal.

It is just the empty form of

```
var a = { bar: "foo"}; // creates an object with the property bar
```

is the same as

```
var a = {};  // creates an object with no user defined properties
a.bar = "foo";  // add the property bar to a
```

The same applies to arrays.

```
var a = [];  // creates an array with no items
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
```

same as

```
var a = [1,2];
```

Answer (score 0):

It will create an empty dictionary.

```
var applicationtypes = {};

// Now you can do things like

applicationtypes['hello'] = 'World!';

// or equivalently

applicationtypes.hello = 'World!';
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

`var applicationtypes = {};` is equivalent to `var applicationtypes = new Object();`

So it is creating an empty object.